# Image uploaded in FTP was 0k with FTPClient

Tags: java, android, file-upload, android-asynctask, ftp

I have a problem with image upload from my android mobile phone to a FTP Area, the FTP work fine, i tried some other interaction with it and i don't have any problem.
The uploaded file weight 0k, name and file extension are right, no error or exception. I do a test to copy the file in another folder and the file copied right.

```
private class FTPUploader extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {


    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        String data = "/pathimage/filename.jpg";
        File sourceFile = new File(data);
        FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
        try {

            con.connect("ftp.ftpServer.it", 21);

            if (con.login("user", "password")) {
                con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode();


                if (sourceFile.exists()) {
                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);


                    boolean result = con.storeFile("/folder/newfilename.jpg", input);
                    input.close();
                    if (result) {
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (sourceFile.exists()) {
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }    
}
```

What i'm wrong about? it's possible manage the event when the upload is finished? thank you in advance for the support

Comment: *"i tried some other interaction with it and i don't have any problem"* - What other interaction? Did you succeed to upload the same file to the same folder on FTP server using any standalone FTP client? + Do you have server-side logs?

Comment: i tried to download a file, read a txt file on FTP and i don't have any problem but if i try to upload i find only the file with name and extention but void. Yes i can upload a file from filezilla and no i'm sorry but i don't have the server-side logs but i can try to find it. This morning i found a workaround with ftp4j, i upload the solution asap.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I find a workaround that works for me. I use the library ftp4j where I can manage the events of the upload and with the System.out.println I can follow the step and be sure for the right upload.
I post in to follow the code. At first, I need to add the library in the libs folder and import it in the build.gradle(Module:app)

```
compile files('libs/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')
```

next i import what i need in the worksheet:

```
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPDataTransferListener;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPIllegalReplyException;
```

And change the code for ftp4j

```
private class FTPUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
        try {
            con.setPassive(true);
            con.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
            con.connect("ftp.server.it");
            con.login("user", "password");
            con.changeDirectory("changeFTPUploadDirectory");
            con.upload(new java.io.File("/path/local/image"), new MyTransferListener());


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
                con.disconnect(true);
        } catch (IOException | FTPException | FTPIllegalReplyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

But what I find very useful is the event management where if there is some problem you can check where and why upload is stopped.

```
public class MyTransferListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {

    public void started() {
        System.out.println("Trasferimento FTP avviato");

    }

    public void transferred(int length) {
        System.out.println("in trasferimento: "+ String.valueOf(length));

    }

    public void completed() {
        System.out.println("Completato");

    }

    public void aborted() {
        System.out.println("Annullato");

    }

    public void failed() {
        System.out.println("Trasferimento fallito");

    }

}
```

As already stated in the top of the post this isn't a solution but a workaround to understand the error.After the edit the code with this change work right. in any way, I search the server-side logs to have more details about my problem. Thank you in advance

documentation -> [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php?lang=en)